# Understanding how JWT auth works

Tags: jwt, refresh-token

I am trying to understand how authentication with jwt works & I have some basic questions.

1) Does the user send both accessToken and refreshToken with each request?

2) If so, how does it send the refreshToken(I know the accessToken is in http header)

3) The server has to first verify the accessToken (with signature) and then check if the expiration time is passed. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Access versus refresh token is not a concept in JWT as far as I know (but it is in OAuth, which uses similar tokens).  Rather, JWT is just a framework which lets a user present his credentials to an authority, but without the possibility of a user somehow modifying that token on his own.

For the second and third parts of your question, typically the JWT would be passed in the header.  Once received, the server, which has the key, may decrypt the token and check *any* claim on that token, including the expiration date.  But note that just checking the expiration date may not be sufficient to grant a user access.  For example, you may have suspended a certain user's account, yet he would still be bearing his JWT.  So, to deal with this, you may have to also hit your user database, in addition to checking claims on the JWT itself.